# `like` clause does not fetch all the results that near to my word

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, sql-like

`like` clause doesn't want to fetching all the results that near to my word, I must write the complete sentence to get it, for instance:

I have the following data in database:

- `Lion king`
- `lionheart`
- `level completed`
- `good morning`

I want to fetch `Lion king`, and when I write this part of word `lion`, in normal it must fetch `Lion king` and `lionheart`, but in my case does not fetch anything, unless, must write the complete sentence to fetch the data.

I tried to use the following queries:

- `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%text'`
- `SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE '%text' OR name LIKE 'text%' OR name LIKE '%text%' OR name LIKE text`

**Notice:**
I'm use `C++ Qt` Framework and the following is what I did

```
qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%:text'");
qry.bindValue(":text", ui->searchBox_txt->text());
qry.exec();
```

**How can I make the query to does the normal behavior ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:text
```

is a query parameter whose name is `text`

```
':text'
```

is the string `":text"`

Similarly, `"%:text"` is exactly what it is; your parameter isn't parsed because it's inside of a string.

You need to concatenate the parameter in with your `'%'` using the concatenation operator (`||`):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%' || :text || '%'
```

Comment: Works great, but I still don't understand why you use `||` , and why does not work when use the normal way `%text%`. can you please simplify the explanation in order to understand.

Comment: @LionKing It's the difference between `x` and `"x"` in other programming languages; one is a variable reference and the other is a string literal.

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry, but I know the difference between `variable` and `literal string`, but I don't know what do you mean of this example `variable` and `literal string`. your explanation still obscure .

Comment: `':text'` is the string ":text"; there's no query parameter in it. `:text` is a query parameter, and will be replaced by the bound value.

Comment: Like I said, it does string concatenation. In this case, it adds the `'%'` characters to be beginning and end of the string.

Comment: Now I understood. but I was know the concatenation symbol is `+` not `||`.

Comment: It depends on the language. In Python and Javascript, it's `+`. In Lua, it's `..`. In SQL, it's `||`. C doesn't even have an operator for it.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `:` after the `%`. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%text%'
```

Please also take note that the value is case sensitive

Comment: This `:` is normal, and I must use it, and not the problem because I'm use `C++ qt framework`.

Comment: Oww.. I see. I just referred it to common SQL Syntax

Comment: The value is not case sensitive.

Comment: Have you tried it in SQL Server? The value there is case sensitive. And thank you for down voting my answer..

Comment: @LouisMichael In SQLite (which is what the question is tagged with), it's case insensitive by default.